# how do i upload a file to a directory in google cloud storage using Google_Client library

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

i want to upload a file to google cloud storage using google client php library on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-storage-ga). Am able to upload file to cloud storage but am not able to upload to a directory in cloud storage. i get the error message `No such object: bucketName/abc/test.jpg`

```
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=files/google_cloud.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$storage = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient([
    'projectId' => $googleprojectID
]);

$sPath = "files/com/test.jpg";
$objectName = "/abc/test.jpg";

$bucketName = $googlebucketName;
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$bucket->upload( fopen($sPath, 'r') );
$object = $bucket->object($objectName);
$info = $object->update(['acl' => []], ['predefinedAcl' => 'PUBLICREAD']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me share with you this documentation page where you will find the complete reference for the [Google Cloud Storage PHP Client Library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.64.0/storage/storageclient). More specifically, if you have a look at [the `upload()` method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.64.0/storage/bucket?method=upload), you will see that in order to set the name of the object uploaded (and therefore its location, given that [GCS has a flat namespace](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)), you have to use the `options` parameter, which can contain a `name` field pointing to the right location to upload.

Also, note that the correct object name should not start with a slash `/`, given that it will automatically be added after the bucket name. Therefore, you should modify your code to add something like this:

```
$sPath = "files/com/test.jpg";
$objectName = "abc/test.jpg"; # Note the removal of "/" here

$options = [
    'name' => $objectName
];

$bucketName = $googlebucketName;
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$bucket -> upload(
    fopen($sPath, 'r'),
    $options
);
```

Comment: thanks very much... and also pointing me to the documentation  

Comment: No worries! I am glad I could help :)